# Filter JSON in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift

I want to filter my JSON and I can't find a way.
My JSON :

```
{
"id": "3",
"nom": "Blancs sablons",
"description": "Plage gigantesque, très souvent des surfeurs à l'eau."
},
{
"id": "4",                                 // id to search
"nom": "Autre nom",                        // text to print
"description": "Encore une description"
},
{
"id": "5",
"nom": "Nom différent",
"description": "Et la dernière description"
},
```

I want to be able to print 'Autre nom' by calling

```
print(Spot[4].description)
```

Where 4 is the id

So I tried this struct Spot with constructor :

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

struct Spot : Decodable {
     let nom : String
     let description : String
     let id: String

init(nom: String, description: String, id: String, img1: String, latitude: String, longitude: String) {
    self.nom = nom
    self.description = description
    self.id = id
    self.img1 = img1
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
}
}
```

And this to decode JSON :

```
func getSpots(){
    guard let downloadURL = URL(string: "http://dronespot.fr/getSpot.php") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print("Oops Call for Help")
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let rates = try decoder.decode([Spot].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print("Error after loading", error)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an array of results back so you just need to select the one that you want out of the array.

In my test code I didn't find one with an id of 4.

You can filter the array using the filter high order function `let rate = rates.filter { $0.id == "36" }`

Here is the code I used in a Playground to test

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

struct Spot : Decodable {
    let nom : String
    let description : String
    let id: String
}

func getSpots(){
    guard let downloadURL = URL(string: "http://dronespot.fr/getSpot.php") else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse, error in

        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print("Oops Call for Help")
            return
        }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let rates = try decoder.decode([Spot].self, from: data)
            let rate = rates.filter { $0.id == "36" }
            print(rate)
        } catch {
            print("Error after loading", error)
        }
    }.resume()
}

getSpots()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Thanks, but it prints the whole line, how can I just print one information, "nom" for example

Comment: print(rate.id) or whatever property you need. rate.nom or rate.description

Comment: rate.first?.id would be better